# My posts are not responsive using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

hello everyone iam building a website in arabic language i use bootstrap and bootstrap RTL ...the website in laptops and desktops (large screen) look very good exacly like i want .....in mobile the navbar and the header and the footer and the widgets look good too 100% responsive ...but posts not responsive at all the thumbnail take most of the screen and the paraghraph start from next the thumbnail and get down too much like in every line just one word....this my posts code in html

```
   <div class="container-fluid" id="container-post">
  <article class="row">

   <section class="col-lg-9">
      <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-body">

           <div class="panel-header">
               <a href="#"><h2>هذا النص يمكن ان يستبدل في نفس المساحة</h2></a>

            </div>
            </p>
            <img src="images/post_img.png" />
            <p >لقد تم توليد هذا النص من مولد النص العربى، حيث يمكنك أن تولد مثل هذا النص أو العديد من النصوص الأخرى إضافة إلى زيادة عدد الحروف التى يولدها ا إذا كنت تحتاج إلى عدد أكبر من الفقرات يتيح لك مولد النص العربى زيادة عدد الفقرات كما تريد،لقد تم توليد هذا النص من مولد النص العربى، حيث يمكنك أن تولد مثل هذا النص أو العديد من النصوص الأخرى إضافة إلى زيادة عدد الحروف التى يولدها ا إذا كنت تحتاج إلى عدد أكبر من الفقرات يتيح لك مولد النص العربى زيادة عدد الفقرات كما تريد، النص لن يبدو مقسما ولا يحوي أخطاء لغوية، مولد النص العربى مفيد لمصممي المواقع على وجه الخصوص، حيث يحتاج العميل فى كثير من الأحيان أن يطلع على صورة حقيقية لتصميما. لموقع. لقد تم توليد هذا النص من مولد النص العربى، حيث يمكنك أن تولد مثل هذا النص أو العديد من النصوص الأخرى إضافة إلى زيادة عدد الحروف التىلقد تم توليد هذا النص من مولد النص العربى، حيث يمكنك أن تولد مثل هذا النص أو العدي</p>


           <div class="read-more">
               <a href="#"><h2>اقرأ المزيد</h2></a>
          </div>
          </div>



       </div>
```

and this is the css code

```css
.panel-header h2 {font-family:Hacen Beirut Poster; margin-top: -10px; color:#27402d;  }
.panel-body {background-color:#b8a97e; border: 1px solid; }
.panel-body p {font-family:Hacen Beirut Poster; font-size: 13pt; float:left; margin-right: 185px; margin-top:-223px;}
.panel-body img {float:right;}
.panel-default {border: none; }
.panel-header :hover {text-decoration: none;}
.read-more h2 {float:left;  font-family:Hacen Beirut Poster;   margin-top:-25px; font-size: 14pt; color:black; background-color: darkgoldenrod; width:80px; line-height: normal; text-align: center;}
.read-more a  {color: white;}
.read-more :hover {color: white;}
.panel  {margin:8px;}
.panel-header  :hover {color:black;}
```

and i tried to make the font small in media query for mobile but the paragraph does not accept to resize in mobile ...i dont know why but the h2 for the title of the post accept but the problem not in the h2 its in the pragraph 
this is my media query code:

```css
@media screen and (max-width:660px){
    
    .panel-body p {font-size: 8pt;}
    
    
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm if this is appearing the same way as in the following js fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/gpeLyrh3/

Comment: no its not the same its too wrong the thumbnail doesnt show  because the photo in my server .....any way you can see the full website from here http://cinemanet.890m.com/BOOTSTAP/